# Переместить таблицы в другую бд с использованием EF Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Есть две базы данных интернет-магазина: Одна основная (контекст наследуется от `DbContext`), другая содержит пользователей (`ApplicationDbContext`, наследуется от `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`). На обеих настроены миграции, которые произвожу раздельно (по этому [гайду](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537558/multiple-db-contexts-in-the-same-db-and-application-in-ef-6-and-code-first-migra)).

Сегодня столкнулся с необходимостью объединить их в одну БД (хостинг ограничивает количество баз), в связи с чем появился вопрос: Как переместить все, например, в основную базу правильно, не нарушив "гомеостаз" EF Code First Migrations и Asp.Net Identity? Получится ли объединить контексты, учитывая, что они наследуются от разных классов? Что делать дальше? Или все обстоит намного проще (например 2 контекста в одной БД)? Прошу пошагово расписать если не действия, то хотя бы логику процесса, который мне необходимо проделать для решения проблемы.

P.S.: Магазин только пишется, пользователь всего 1, так что пересоздание таблицы с пользователями не страшно. Лишь бы на выходе все работало.

UPD:

Прикрепляю класс основного контекста по просьбе @Bald:

```
public class ProductContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductType> ProductTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TopNote> TopNotes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<HeartNote> HeartNotes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BaseNote> BaseNotes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Feature> Features { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductValue> ProductValues { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Variation> Variations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Visitor> Visitors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany(c => c.ProductTypes)
            .WithMany(s => s.Products)
            .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("ProductId")
            .MapRightKey("ProductTypeId")
            .ToTable("Product_ProductTypes"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany(c => c.TopNotes)
            .WithMany(s => s.Products)
            .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("ProductId")
            .MapRightKey("TopNoteId")
            .ToTable("Product_TopNotes"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany(c => c.HeartNotes)
            .WithMany(s => s.Products)
            .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("ProductId")
            .MapRightKey("HeartNoteId")
            .ToTable("Product_HeartNotes"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany(c => c.BaseNotes)
            .WithMany(s => s.Products)
            .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("ProductId")
            .MapRightKey("BaseNoteId")
            .ToTable("Product_BaseNotes"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany(c => c.ProductValues)
        .WithMany(s => s.Products)
        .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("ProductId")
        .MapRightKey("ProductValueId")
        .ToTable("Product_ProductValues"));
        }
    }
```

и класс ApplicationDbContext, на всякий случай:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("ApplicationDbContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Bald Мешало то, что в языке еще относительный новичок. Не могу сказать, что не думал об этом выходе, но останавливал страх менять что-то связанное с identity, потому что слабо с ним знаком и велик шанс что-то «сломать». Не могли бы вы описать последовательность действий, которая поможет мне перенести контекст identity в основной и полноценно работать с получившимся контекстом без ругани EF Code First (в свое время сильно с ним намучился, как с ребенком) и, скажем так, не упустить какие-нибудь хвосты?

Comment: @Bald Пока не вник в эту тему. Планирую, конечно использовать, но на данном этапе использую только дефолтную авторизацию ASP.NET Identity. Это авторизация на сайт (1 пользователь — предполагается, что покупатель — для проверки фильтров и прочего). Админка пока без авторизации (еще предстоит изучать логику ролей, клэймов и т. д.). Так что identity максимально соответствует изначальному при создании приложения, насколько я могу судить.

Comment: @Bald то есть перенести основной контекст в `public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`? Не понял, что такое `public DbSet<History> Histories {get;set;}`.

Comment: добавьте в исходный вопрос Ваш `class` который Вы называете основным контекстом, т.е. тот который наследует от `DbContext`

Comment: перенесите содержимое `ProductContext` в `ApplicationDbContext`

Comment: «Ciel2.Models.IdentityUserRole: : Для EntityType "IdentityUserRole" не определены ключи. Определите ключ для этого EntityType» (и то же для `IdentityUserLogin`).
«IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: Набор EntitySet "IdentityUserRoles" основан на типе "IdentityUserRole", в котором не определены ключи» (и то же самое для `IdentityUserLogins`). Ругается на `public ActionResult LoginPartial()`.

Comment: постараюсь в ближайшее время проверить на тестовом проекте, я правильно понял что Вы создали [tag:asp.net-mvc] проект, в нем создали второй контекст, больше никаких изменений не делали?!

Comment: @Bald Это было довольно давно. Возможно еще, что я создавал приложение без Identity, а позднее добавил его по одному из гайдов в интернете. Но скорее всего так, как сказали вы. Точно знаю, что до перемещения ProductContext авторизация работала: при регистрации добавлялись пользователи (даже свое поле добавил в контекст пользователя — FirstName), авторизация проходит без проблем. UPD: Ошибки, описанные мной выше, также выбрасываются при попытке сгенерировать миграцию для `ApplicationDbContext`.

Comment: а после того как Вы добавили содержимое `ProductContext` в `ApplicationDbContext` Вы сделали *миграцию*? на тестовом проекте у меня все получилось

Comment: При попытке миграции, выходит ошибка:

"One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

Ciel2.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Ciel2.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined."

Comment: меня смущает что он у Вас ругается на `UserLogin`, `UserRole` их в проекте по умолчанию нет, а вот в `nuget` пакете asp.net-identity-sample есть.

Comment: так может их снести просто, если они не нужны для identity? Поиск "IdentityUserRole" по всему решению не дает результатов.

Comment: не совсем понял, откуда Вы их снести хотите?! скажите установлен ли у Вас `nuget` пакет [Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Samples 2.1.0-alpha1](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples/2.1.0-alpha1)

Comment: Такого нет. С Identity есть Core, EF, Owin и русские ресурсы к ним.

Comment: попробуйте создать новый проект и *перетащите* туда пару своих классов, только не создавай новый контекст а в существующий добавляй `public DbSet<>`

Comment: Нашел решение тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994590/asp-net-identity-validation-error. Спасибо @Bald за уделенное время.

Comment: ну раз Вы нашли решение, то может Вы тогда и ответите на свой же вопрос, т.е. переведите ответ который Вам помог с указанием исходного ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил задачу переносом основного контекста в `ApplicationDbContext` (спасибо @Bald).

После такого объединения контекстов, при попытке провести Code First Migrations консоль выдала ошибку:

```
"One or more validation errors were detected during model generation: Ciel2.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType. Ciel2.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType. IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined. IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined."
```

После нескольких дней поисков, нашел ответ тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994590/asp-net-identity-validation-error.

Суть проблемы вкратце (а также решение): Наличие в контексте данных сущностей, связанных отношением многие-ко-многим, вынуждает к переопределению метода `OnModelCreating` (что отражено в моем коде). Таким образом для корректной работы объединенных контекстов необходимо приписать:

`base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);`

непосредственно перед основным содержанием метода. После этих изменений миграция заработала и никаких проблем с Entity Framework больше не возникает. Полностью мой окончательный контекст данных выглядит так (не обращайте внимание на разницу в сущностях, за время работы он немного вырос):

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public string AvatarUrl { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        Addresses = new List<Address>();
    }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductType> ProductTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TopNote> TopNotes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<HeartNote> HeartNotes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BaseNote> BaseNotes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Feature> Features { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductValue> ProductValues { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Variation> Variations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Visitor> Visitors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Fav> Favs { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderStatus> OrderStatuses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); // та самая строка кода

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany(c => c.ProductTypes)
            .WithMany(s => s.Products)
            .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("ProductId")
            .MapRightKey("ProductTypeId")
            .ToTable("Product_ProductTypes"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany(c => c.TopNotes)
            .WithMany(s => s.Products)
            .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("ProductId")
            .MapRightKey("TopNoteId")
            .ToTable("Product_TopNotes"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany(c => c.HeartNotes)
            .WithMany(s => s.Products)
            .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("ProductId")
            .MapRightKey("HeartNoteId")
            .ToTable("Product_HeartNotes"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany(c => c.BaseNotes)
            .WithMany(s => s.Products)
            .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("ProductId")
            .MapRightKey("BaseNoteId")
            .ToTable("Product_BaseNotes"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany(c => c.ProductValues)
        .WithMany(s => s.Products)
        .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("ProductId")
        .MapRightKey("ProductValueId")
        .ToTable("Product_ProductValues"));
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("ApplicationDbContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {

    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Еще раз большое спасибо пользователю @Bald и сайту StackOverflow за помощь в решении задачи.